# How to find critical points of functionals when there is a boundary?

Tags: elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Banach spaces have a relatively uninteresting topology, because they are contractible. This prevents the direct application of Morse-like min-max arguments to establish the existence of critical points. However, there is a trick that works $X$ is a Banach space and $F: X \to \mathbf{R}$ is an *even* functional, that is
\begin{equation}
F(-x) = F(x) \quad \text{ for all $x \in X$}.
\end{equation}
Specifically, one can quotient $X$ by the $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-action; the quotient $X / \pm 1$ is now an infinite-dimensional projective space, and its topology can be used to construct critical points.

Typically $X$ is a function space, say $W^{1,2}(M)$ for example, defined on a compact manifold *without boundary*.

> Can this method be used when $X$ is a function space over a manifold $M$ *with non-empty boundary*, and $F: X \to \mathbf{R}$ is still even? (I am interested primarily in the case where the boundary data is non-zero.)

Answer (score 2):

The boundary case works without any major change (at least for a reasonable functional). For example, if you consider the Allen--Cahn energy $E_\epsilon$ and take $W^{1,2}(M)$ then critical points of $E_{\epsilon}$ will be solutions to Allen--Cahn with Neumann boundary conditions.

In the original papers (Guraco, Gaspar--Guaraco) this was not considered. However in [their later paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04243) they discuss the case of boundary, e.g. the remark after Theorem 2.1 (or just search the pdf for "boundary" for more comments).

Comment: Thanks Otis, that's interesting! So there's no way of doing min-max with a Dirichlet boundary condition? Taking the Allen-Cahn functional as an example, say we have some boundary function $g: \partial M \to \mathbf{R}$ for which there exist multiple stable solutions. I guess one-parameter min-max should be OK, but are you saying there's no way of defining multi-parameter min-max among functions with $u = g$ on $\partial M$?

Comment: I think that you can also do Dirichlet boundary conditions no problem. Just use $W_0^{1,2}$ or more generally $E_\epsilon(\cdot + g)$ on $W_0^{1,2}$ for some extension of $g$. However, it's not clear to me what you get in this situation (note that the estimates $\omega_p \sim p^{1/n+1}$ is unlikely to hold in this setting unless you choose the boundary conditions in some clever way.

Comment: Hmm, the natural $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-action on functions $u \in W^{1,2}(M)$ with $u = g$ would be $u \mapsto -u + 2g$. But the functional wouldn't be invariant under this action, as $E(-u + 2g) = E(u - 2g) \neq E(u)$. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Whoops I was too hasty. I guess only g=0 makes sense in this setting. It would be interesting to understand the growth rate of the corresponding p widths.